# Azure DevOps service accounts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there a concept of service accounts for Azure DevOps pipelines? I have a task (connecting to SharePoint Online) which I would like to perform using a service account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about service connections, which you can use in Azure DevOps pipelines. You can use it with

```
azureSubscription: `<your-service-connection`
```

in your pipeline (for instance to connect with SharePoint online). You can more useful information in Microsoft's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

P.S. you can also log in to Sharepoint Online with

```
npm install -g @pnp/office365-cli &&
o365 spo login https://$(tenant).sharepoint.com/$(catalogsite) — authType password — userName $(username) — password $(password)
```

where you can save the tenant, catalogsite, username and password as secret variables. For more info: https://stridelysolutions.medium.com/how-to-setup-azure-devops-with-sharepoint-framework-5b7e570bbcc9